# Android and Borderless Ripple

Tags: android, imageview, material-design, ripple

This is my layout file:

```
<data></data>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_rootcontainer_RL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_container_RL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/login_logo_IV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_app" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_signintext_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/login_logo_IV"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Sign in"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_socialcontainer_LL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/login_signintext_TV"
                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/login_facebook_IV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_facebook_letter" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/login_twitter_IV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_twitter_letter" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/login_google_IV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    style="@style/DefaultSelectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_googleplus_letter" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/login_linkedin_IV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    style="@style/DefaultSelectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_linkedin_letter" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_signinor_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/login_socialcontainer_LL"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="or"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/signin_name_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/login_socialcontainer_LL"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/login_socialcontainer_LL"
                android:layout_below="@id/login_signinor_TV"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/signin_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/signin_email_hint"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/signin_password_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/signin_name_container"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signin_name_container"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signin_name_container"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/signin_name_container"
                android:layout_below="@+id/signin_name_container"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="false"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/signin_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_forgotpassword_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/signin_password_container"
                android:layout_below="@id/signin_password_container"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Forgot password"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_terms_TV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Don't have an account yet? Sign up!"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is the DefaultSelectableItemBackgroundBorderless:

```
<style name="DefaultSelectableItemBackground" >
    <item name="android:theme">@style/DefaultSelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
<style name="DefaultSelectableItemBackgroundBorderless" >
    <item name="android:theme">@style/DefaultSelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>
<style name="DefaultSelectableItemTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I don't see any ripple effect when the user clicks on ImageView or ImageButton. In the Java code I've set the .setOnClickListener on the ImageView and ImageButton.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set background for ImageView as `android:background=?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`.